# why getting error while loading font in sfml

Tags: c++, fonts, sfml

I started working on SFML C++ and Iam getting the error 'access violation reading location' on loadFromFile line in visual studio 2019 however I kept the font file in same directory but still its unable to load font.

```
sf::Font font;
    
if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
{
    std::cout << "Error loading font !";
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the hints of the [tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-text.php)? _The loadFromFile function can sometimes fail with no obvious reason. First, check the error message that SFML prints to the standard output (check the console)..._

Comment: Looks similar to https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9738.15, please provide a [mre]

Comment: ... _However, when you launch your program from your IDE (Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, ...) the working directory might sometimes be set to the project directory instead. This can usually be changed quite easily in the project settings._ Namely from VS, I'm used to that the default working directory is the one where the binaries (`.exe`, `.dll`s) are written to. That's not the source directory but it can be adjusted in the projects Debugging settings.

Comment: changing cwd didn't worked !

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the location of your font file on your drive. The error you speak of is given by Visual Studio when it is unable to access a memory location. If it was your font you'd see the error in the command console of your program, something like:

```
Error loading font : Cannot find "xyz.ttf"
```

As for the solution please check your linker configuration and if you have resolved all dependencies. In your case the library you're looking for is "freetype.lib". Here's the proper [guide](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) on how to link and the correct order of linking your SFML libraries and their dependencies. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's 3 years late, but I ran into an access violation as well when using it.

If you initialize the font in a local function and call `setFont` with that locally created font, then it will result in a crash because the font gets unloaded after the function is executed.

`Fix:` Call new on the font and load, or store it as a data-member in the class that is using the font.